# Как обрезать или дописать лишние байты в строке?

Tags: c#, строки, utf-8, byte, работа-с-текстом

Допустим, у нас есть строка в UTF-8. Она должна занимать в памяти ровно 38 байт. Ни больше, не меньше, чтобы не допустить смещение указателей. Символы там могут занимать как один, так и два байта. Как это реализовать наиболее просто в C#? Размер строки в байтах хранится в int переменной.

Comment: а если байтов недостаточно, то чем вы их собираетесь дополнять?

Comment: Забить нулями. 00 в hex

Comment: В C# нет «строк в UTF-8». Строка в C# вовсе не имеет кодировки. Вы имеете в виду массив байт? И о каких указателях идёт речь? В C# нет указателей.

Comment: В C# указателей нет, зато в игре, редактор ресурсов которой я модифицирую, указатели есть. И игра будет виснуть, если экспортируемый текст будет больше или меньше.

Comment: Команда NLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(tempText); спокойно подсчитывает размер строки в байтах.

Comment: @zamanov001: Нет, она подсчитывает не размер строки в байтах. Она подсчитывает количество байт, необходимое для представления этой строки в кодировке UTF-8. Тот же код с другой кодировкой подсчитает количество байт, необходимое для представления этой же строки в другой кодировке. А у самой строки кодировки нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы узнать длину в байтах в конкретной кодировке есть метод GetByteCount, от него и нужно плясать. А вообще в UTF-8 символ может и 3, и 4 байтами кодироваться, но не суть.
Например метод возвращающий массив байтов определённой длины с обрезанной или наоборот дополненной стройкой в определённой кодировке.

```
byte[] GetCutBytes(string str, int maxlength, Encoding encoding)
{
    char[] charArray = str.ToCharArray();
    int length = charArray.Length;
    while (encoding.GetByteCount(charArray, 0, length) > maxlength)
        length--;

    byte[] returned = new byte[maxlength];
    encoding.GetBytes(charArray, 0, length, returned, 0);
    return returned;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вышло идеально! Добавил только Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returned);

Comment: @zamanov001: Если вам нужна строка, то вместо последних трёх строчек напишите просто `return str.Substring(0, length)`.

Comment: Немного поколдовал, хз насколько корректно: `char[] charArray = tempText.ToCharArray(); Array.Resize<char> (ref charArray, Text.OLength); Text = new string(charArray);`

Comment: @zamanov001 Увы, некорректно. Ваш код не учитывает длину в байтах в кодировке. Сами попробуйте 3 русских буквы и длину в 5 символов.